# Breeze and Web API (gui and no gui)

Tags: breeze

I'm building a new SPA, and I'm having some problems dealing with what appear to be conflicting concerns.

So, on the surface, the SPA is fairly basic CRUD.  However, there's a catch:  They also want all of the functionality to be available as Web API.

That *sounds* like a fit, given that Breeze works on top of Web API, but I keep feeling that I'm pounding a square peg into a round hole. Can someone give me a tow?

Example of the issue:

Suppose I have a screen for creating/adding widgets.

- There are some validations
- There are some business rules (if the widget weighs over 5 lbs, call another web service that sends an email)

So, with Breeze, that's pretty easy.  I just hook up my EFContext Provider, and hook the BeforeSaveEntity(ies) events and go to town.

This is great, but they want a CreateWidget web API.  It's not going to be acceptable for the client to have to build a Breeze compatible JObject bundle to simulate the save.

The API would seem to want a conventional DTO/Domain Service sort of thing.  Something like:

```
string CreateWidget(widgetDto)
```

Breeze's client side library is fantastic, and I want to be able to use it for my GUI app. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use Breeze and still separate concerns on my server side so that the domain services are usable from an imperative API, and so that they will support unit testing.

(I know you can override SaveCore, and I've looked at the NoDb example, but the important part just says something like "// your code would go here". Every avenue that I try smells like a huge hack, because really, Breeze wants control of the whole vertical stack on the server, and I just want it to decode the breeze client posts back to my DTOs so that I can map to the same domain services that my API will use, and then I want to traffic errors raised by my services back to the client (which we surface with the really excellent wzValidate angular directive).

I have read a lot of posts of people saying that if you really feel that you need DTOs, then you can use them, but I have come up empty searching for a working example that also incorporates business logic on the server.  Can someone point me to a good resource?

Comment: Working on a substantive reply. Should post soon

Comment: Thank you @Ward!  We're loving how easy it is to create the GUI with Breeze!  If can just work out this part, we will have a great solution!

Comment: @Ward So here's a business rule that I'm not sure how I would implement with the ContextProvider:  a specific type of record has a user-entered id.  The ID must be unique to any records created by that user.  If the user left the ID blank, we want to set it equal to the primary key of the record (it's a db-generated ID key).  I get how to do that in a sproc, or using EF directly(an extra round-trip for a new record).  I'm not sure how I could make that happen with the EFContextProvider.

Comment: I'd need more details (such as what the db does if the ID is supplied vs. left null) but herewith some hints. You have [several extension points](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/contextprovider) to intervene including `BeforeSave...`, `SaveChangesCore`, and `AfterSaveEntities`. You can wrap the entire operation in a separate transaction if you need to make multiple db store calls that must all succeed-or-fail together. The `saveBundle` change-set is malleable throughout the process. You may have a few hacky moments but its not terrible if you don't make a habit of it.

Comment: You can always fall back on the fact that the save objects at the service boundary (`saveBundle` in; `SaveResult` out) are pretty simple and the `ContextProvider` is open source. You can always channel the trickier save operations to a dedicated save endpoint (called a "named save" in the docs) where you can do whatever you want with whatever server-code feels good to you. I wouldn't feel badly about this route if I only took it occasionally. If it seems like everything I do requires bypassing the Breeze server-side helpers than I'd take a different course (to be discussed as needed).

Comment: @Ward I was able to get my pattern to work by hooking the AfterSaveEntities delegate.  I have explored creating my own ContextProvider, and might go down that route.  I have also looked at perhaps writing a different sort of server-side handler (not a context provider), but remaining compatible with Breeze by returning a BreezeSaveResult.  Still pretty early in my thought process, but something that would convert the incoming JObject to DTO's and then allow me to convert the entities back to DTO's for the save (would have to still provide keymap and entity state though so still thinking)

Comment: That makes sense. We need to explore DTO-oriented backend support more thoroughly. You're headed there. Stay in touch :-)

Comment: @Ward I definitely will!